# Purpose of 2 resistors and a diode in a MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, mosfet-driver

[image: schematic]

What is the purpose of diodes D2B and D3B please?  From what I have read elsewhere, they are to slow down the turn off of the MOSFET.  Why are there two resistors?

> With modern MOSFETs the switching speeds increase every year. The severity of the turn-off snap recovery is a function of the MOSFET switching speed. A MOSFET turn-on is what caused the diode to turn off in the first place. So, a simple solution is to slow the MOSFET down. Yes, why use fast MOSFETs. Well, we just want to slow down the MOSFET turn-on:

Quote from [*Synertronic Designs: Common cause of EMI in power electronics - the diode*](http://www.synertronic.co.za/post/2013/05/07/Common-cause-of-EMI-in-power-electronics-the-diode)

Comment: Asymmetric gate drive.

Answer (score 3):

Since the MOSFETs are N-channel the positive gate drive to turn on the devices is through the 68 ohm resistor, the diode is reverse biased.

However, when turning off the device the diode conducts allowing current through the 10 ohm resistor as well to allow more rapid turn-off.

One reason to do this is to minimize the time that both MOSFETS are conducting when used in a half-bridge in a DC-DC converter. If both transistors are conducting at the same time current will pass directly from +BAT to -BAT (referred to as shoot-through). By having a slow turn-on and rapid turn-off this can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It's like Kevin wrote. A high switch-off speed prevents both transistors of the half-bridge from conducting at the same time and thus causing a short circuit.

But essentially the design is about charging and discharging the mosfet with different time constants. The aim is not to shift too fast or too slowly. Switching too fast causes EMC issues and too slow power loss in the semiconductor.

Answer (score 0):

They are used to discharge quickly MOSFET's VHB and VLB through R8B and R9B which are smaller than R2B and R3B.